# How to count where using DB::raw() in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query, but it does not work

```
$order = Order::select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as num_product'),
DB::raw('count(status) where status = 1 as accepted')) // ERROR HERE
->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"))->get();
```

I want to show number of order that accepted, for example : 2 of 5

Comment: Why you not using simple Laravel Eloquent : `$order = Order::where('status', 1)->count()`;

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = Order::select(DB::raw('count(*) as num_product, status'))
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->groupBy('status')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"))
    ->get();
```

Comment: I have 4 data and I need to group it by date, then show status is accepted or not